# Reading a file in python 3.x as Bytes/Strings for PySerial/Xmodem

Tags: python, unicode, ascii, pyserial, xmodem

I'm trying to read a binary file into a buffer and then transmit it using pyserial/xmodem.

my test code:

```
send_buf = open('test.py', 'rb') 
xmInst = XMODEM(self.getc, self.putc)
xmInst.send (send_buf)
```

xmodem send code:

```
...
data = stream.read(packet_size)
if not data:
    break/
total_packets += 1
data = data.ljust(packet_size, self.pad)
```

However, when it executes that last line it says
'must be a byte string of length 1, not str'.     Presumably a byte / string / unicode issue?

The xmodem package was written for python 2.7, so how do I read/pass the file in Python 3.4 such that xmodem can work with it?

Comment: probably `self.pad` is not a single byte character but a `str`. try printing `repr(self.pad)`

Comment: putting a  'print( repr(self.pad) )' just before the last line outputs:  '\x1a'.   So looks like it's a single byte.    So if the idea is that it's trying to pad the contents of the file with 0x1A until it's a full packet size?    Is there another way to do this?    (BTW, I tried using 2to3 on the xmodem file but it didn't convert)

Comment: Byte strings in Python 3.4 look like `b'\x1a'` (type `bytes`). `self.pad` is a Unicode string (type `str`).

Comment: So how can I convert from byte to string or the other way around?  I tried 'data = data.ljust(packet_size, self.pad.decode(encoding)), but 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'.